# How to detect tap on Google maps text window

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Can google_maps_flutter detect tap on map TextInfo window (not marker)?
If so, how to recognize which window has been tapped?

Additional question - is it possible to make custom window with icon and buttons?

With Swift i can do it without any problem, but now I'm converting my app to flutter.

Below screen from my Swift app I try to achieve.

[image: Sample screen]

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this is a developer preview at version 0.2.  Many things probably don't work yet.